# yield scrapy.Request() not working properly for crawling next page

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

The same code works for the different site but not with this one!

**site = http://quotes.toscrape.com/**

It doesn't give any error and successfully craws 8 pages (or count pages)
        import scrapy

```
    count = 8

    class QuotesSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'quotes_spider'
        allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
        start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

        def parse(self, response):
            quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')

            for quote in quotes:
                text = quote.xpath('.//*[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
                author = quote.xpath('.//*[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first()

                yield{
                    'Text' : text,
                    'Author' : author
                }

            global count
            count = count - 1
            if(count > 0):
                next_page = response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
                absolute_next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page)
```

But it crawls only 1st page for this site

**site https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/7**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

count = 5

class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ["goodreads.com/list/show/7"]
    start_urls = ["https://goodreads.com/list/show/7/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//tr/td[3]')

        for book in books:
            bookTitle = book.xpath('.//*[@class="bookTitle"]/span/text()').extract_first()
            authorName = book.xpath('.//*[@class="authorName"]/span/text()').extract_first()

            yield{
                'BookTitle' : bookTitle,
                'AuthorName' : authorName
            }

        global count
        count = count - 1

        if (count > 0):
            next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="pagination"]/a[@class="next_page"]/@href').extract_first()
            absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = absolute_next_page_url)
```

**I want to crawl certain limited pages or all pages of 2nd site.**

Comment: I am getting this Debugging Error:
DEBUG : Filtered offsite request to 'www.go
odreads.com': <GET https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/7.Best_Books_of_the_21st_Century?page=2>

I've tried many solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the allowed_domains settings ? I don't see why this should be included here and your error seems to refer to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a domain with path in `allowed_domains`.

```
allowed_domains = ["goodreads.com/list/show/7"]
```

should be

```
allowed_domains = ["goodreads.com"]
```